# После запуска Intellij idea исчезает модуль проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, модули

[image: После запуска Intellij idea исчезает модуль проекта.]
Если всё настроить вручную оно зароботает, но если снова закрить і открить Idea проблема возвращается

Comment: Попробуйте удалить `*.iml` файл

Answer (score 1):

Судя по желтой обводке iml файла, весь проект криво создан. 
Попробуй удалить его и через `File -> New -> Project from existing sources` создать проект заново.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не сохраняется конфигурация модуля, которая должна храниться в `.iml` файле. Обычно ИИ оставляет эти файлы в папке модуля. Причина вами не указана, поэтому трудно вам дать какой-то совет. Я бы на вашем месте проверил, можно ли писать в файл модуля и доступен ли он. Для этого можно создать небольшой проект который читает файл.